# Each row to be in  different bgcolors in jquery datatable

Tags: jquery, datatables

I have requirement to display each row of **jquery datatable** in a different color. For ex: if the data set has 20 records. The 20 Records to be displayed in different color. Please any one help me.....

Comment: Do the colors need to be the same every time a user visits the page?

Answer (score 2):

To expand upon DKSan's answer (and with the assumption that his code works!), add the random generation to the fnRowCallback, which is an available DataTables initialization parameter:

```
// you don't have to pass everything in if all you're using is nRow
"fnRowCallback": function( nRow, aData, iDisplayIndex, iDisplayIndexFull ) {
  var randomColor = '#'+(Math.random()*0xFFFFFF<<0).toString(16));
  $(nRow).css('background-color', randomColor);

  return nRow;
}
```

There's a whole bunch of stuff you could do instead of using entirely random colours. If you make an array of available colours (say 20), you could increment an index variable (with scope outside the fnRowCallback) and cycle through. Or you could just draw upon a random colour from your set of available colors with some sort of "no two in a row" test.

Answer (score 0):

you could try this piece of code and run it for each row. Not 100% guaranteed to give you 20 different colors, but very likely.

`'#'+(Math.random()*0xFFFFFF<<0).toString(16))`

To have it 100% sure, save the generated strings in an array and test every new creation against each element in the array before adding